# Different partials for same Cocoon nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb, cocoon-gem

I'm using cocoon gem to add multiple dates linked to a job.

I want to give the person creating the job the option to:

1) add a fixed-schedule -> start_date, **end_date**, start_hour, end_hour

2) add a flexible schedule with multiple dates -> start_date, start_hour and end_hour

I created option 2 now, which is fully functional, in which he can just keep adding start_dates with the related working hours. (flexible schedule)

Now I have created 2 tabs (bootstrap) for fixed schedule (1) or flexible schedule (2).

Cocoon requires the partial to be named a specific way, so I guess I cannot just simply create 2 partials to render one with and one without end day.

My question is:

How can I add 2 different versions of the nested form? (one with the end_date)
Can I do something like if aria-expanded = true show these fields, else these?
Is that possible with erb or do I need to use some js to get the job done?
Or am I completely wrong and is it possible to create 2 different partials that I render according to which bootstrap tab is open?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Structure looks something like following (very simplified):

```
simple_form_for @vacancies
  fields for vacancies
  bootstrap-tabs flexible / fixed schedule
  flexible schedule
    simple_fields_for 
     render the partial without the end date
  fixed schedule
     ?? <- stuck here
```

**Actual code - View**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row create-form">
      <%= simple_form_for @vacancy do |f| %>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
          <%= f.hidden_field :recruiter_id, value: current_recruiter.id %>
          <%= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "job title"%>
          <%= f.input :address, label: false, placeholder: "location", input_html: {id: "user_input_autocomplete_address" } %>
          <%= f.input :description, label: false, placeholder: "description", :input_html => {:rows => 7}  %>
          <%= f.input :jobtype_id, collection: Jobtype.all, label: false, prompt: "sector"%>
          <%= f.input :jobterm_id, collection: Jobterm.all, label: false, prompt: "Contract type"%>
          <%= f.input :wage_cents, label: false, placeholder: "wage (optional)" %>
        </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#fixed" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Fixed schedule</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#flex" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Flexible schedule</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="fixed">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <!-- What do I do here? make new partial? Put if structure in current to see if this one is open or not? -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="flex">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <%= f.simple_fields_for :vacancyschedules do |vacancyschedule| %>
                <div id="vacancyschedules">
                  <%= render "vacancyschedule_fields", f: vacancyschedule %>
                </div>
              <% end %>
              <div class="links">
                <%= link_to_add_association '', f, :vacancyschedules, class:'fa fa-plus-circle' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
```

.

```
          <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Code in partial (currently without end_date since I dont know wether to add it here or new partial**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="inline" style="display: flex">
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.input :start_hour, as: :time, default: Time.parse('09:00')%>
    </div>
    <div class="field" style="padding-left: 20px;">
      <%= f.input :end_hour, as: :time, default: Time.parse('17:00')%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 field date-field" style="">
    <%= f.text_field :start_date, placeholder: "start date", class: 'form-control', data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' }, label: false, error: false  %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "X", f %>
</div>
```

**Visualisation - As you can see, flex works fine, just need to figure out how to add the extra end_day field when fixed is clicked.**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two different options:

#### Two links

If I understand correctly, you have two tabs, each tab has its own  `link_to_add_association`. It is possible to overrule the [partial](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#partial) that is rendered, so one link could render the *default* tab, and for the other you write

```
= link_to_add_association 'add something', f, :something, partial: 'fixed_schedule_fields'
```

#### Use a js callback

Instead of using real tabs, you have fake tabs and a single `link_to_add_association` link, and in the callback you check which tab is active, and hide the superfluous field (and maybe set some default values). See [documentation](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#callbacks-upon-insert-and-remove-of-items).